# Syntax error when multiplying variables in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to multiply two variables within VB Studio, however I am getting a syntax error when trying to do this.

`(Quantity * ItemCost)` gives me a syntax error on the first bracket, and removing the brackets gives me the error that method arguments must be enclosed in parenthesis.

Sorry if this was rather vague or really obvious, I am new to programming in general and am doing my best to make simple programs. I know my code is far from the most efficient but it's the best I can do at the moment.
The whole of my code is below :

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim CustomerName As String
    Dim Pensioner As Boolean
    Dim Takeout As Boolean
    Dim Items(4) As Array
    Dim CostOfItems(4) As Array
    Dim Alpha As Integer = 0
    Dim Quantity As Integer
    Dim ItemCost As Integer

    Private Sub txtName_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtName.TextChanged
        CustomerName = txtName.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboItemName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboItemName.SelectedIndexChanged
        If cboItemName.Text = "Tea" Then
            txtItemPrice.Text = "£0.50"
        ElseIf cboItemName.Text = "Coffee" Then
            txtItemPrice.Text = "£0.70"
        ElseIf cboItemName.Text = "Orange Juice" Then
            txtItemPrice.Text = "£0.80"
        ElseIf cboItemName.Text = "Apple Juice" Then
            txtItemPrice.Text = "£0.80"
        ElseIf cboItemName.Text = "Potato" Then
            txtItemPrice.Text = "£1.00"
        End If
        ItemCost = txtItemPrice.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtQuantity_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtQuantity.KeyPress


        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
        Quantity = txtQuantity.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        If chxPension.Checked = True Then
            Pensioner = True
            chxPension.Hide()
        End If
        If cbxTakeOut.Checked = True Then
            TakeOut = True
            cbxTakeOut.Hide()
        End If
        Quantity * ItemCost
        txtQuantity.Text = ""
        cboItemName.Text = ""
        Alpha += 1
        txtName.ReadOnly = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

(I have now changed the `ItemCost` value to not include a £ or . , however I am still getting a syntax error on the bracket)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not assigning the *result* of the multiplication to any variable. Some languages permit that (calculating a value and throwing it away), but apparently VB.NET doesn't. It is trying to save you from a common programmer mistake.

Do it like this instead:

```
Dim TotalCost As Integer = Quantity * ItemCost
```

The result of the multiplication will now be stored in the variable `TotalCost`, which you can use for whatever you need.

Of course, you could also store the result of the calculation in one of the operand variables (assuming, of course, it is not a constant). In this case, judging from the names of the variables, it doesn't make much sense, but sometimes it is appropriate:

```
ItemCost = Quantity * ItemCost   ' probably wrong, but syntactically legal
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I never thought of including the calculation where I declared the variables. I did try to include Quantity * ItemCost = Total , but that still left the syntax error

Comment: @CalBar If this answer solved your question, please mark it as the answer (Green check mark under the upvote/downvote signs) so other will see it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to declare your variables correctly.
item cost can not be integer.

Item cost should be something like double or decimal

```
Dim TotalCost as Decimal = Quantity * ItemCost
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please remove the `£` in your `txtItemPrice.Text`?

Replace this in your existing codes:
`ItemCost = cInt(txtItemPrice.Text)`
`Quantity = cInt(txtQuantity.Text)`

This is to convert the `Strings (.text)` into `Integer`

For the computation of Total Cost:
`Dim Total As Integer = Quantity * ItemCost`

**Please Take Note:**
`Integer` data types **cannot** hold values with **decimal**. Use `Double` instead.